# Is there an easy way to restrict a group to 2 screens only?

Tags: c#, silverlight

In my Silverlight application,  I have 15+ screens.   I want a permission group 'CanOnlySeeTraining' to NOT have access to all screens except 2 of them.  I know I can put the code below but the thing is I have to put this code for each and EVERY screen that I have out there except the 2 that I want them to see.   Is there a way in Silverlight C# to say to put a permission from the top and flow down the screen tree(like Windows folder permissions)?  Let me know if you need more clarification.  Thanks.

```
partial void <ScreenName>_CanRun(ref bool result)
    {
        if (this.User.HasPermission(Permissions.CanOnlySeeTraining))
        {
            result = false;
        }
        else
        {
            result = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

We don't do this exactly, but... Our app assigns an 'activity id' to each window (or batch process, we have several), and a standard part of startup in each is to check if the user's permission group has access to that activity.  We have a general function that compares group & activity to determine if that combination is allowed; that function just returns a flag value that says whether or not the startup should continue. *Everything* uses the 'start-up allowed' check function and only continues if it is specifically allowed.  Nobody needs to have any specific check like your sample, they just need to know if they are allowed to continue right now.

Our relation data is kept in a database table but it would be fairly trivial to move that to a file.

Our implementation relies on inheritance to ensure the check function doesn't get skipped and only a few base objects (two, I think) actually have the check coded.

Comment: Thanks DaveE.   Can you elaborate more or provide code examples on how you did it?   Thanks.

Comment: We have a table that defines the controlled activities (usually application screens), another pair that define users and user groups, one that links users to groups, and a final linking table that associates controlled activities with user groups and a permission level (none, read-only, modify, create, or supervisor (for workflows requiring approvals)). There's standard code that checks to see what permissions a user has to an activity and sets the screen-level object permissions appropriately. If they don't have permission to a screen, it doesn't appear in any menu.